# Who decides what to add to the new JavaScript versions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecma

I'm curious. Ecma International, Mozilla Team, W3?
And what is the official website where people suggest changes to new js versions and discuss it?

why i ask it. because they influent all of us. They can improve the langugae and they can destroy it with some bad changes.

And what is the official website where people suggest changes to new js versions and discuss it? - answered in comments. thanks. https://github.com/tc39 and https://esdiscuss.org (mozilla)

Comment: I am sure it is not me :)

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/memento/tc39-rf-tg.htm

Comment: https://github.com/tc39, https://esdiscuss.org/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-ecmascript-cba48c73a2b5) gives a nice overview of JavaScript and how it is related to ECMAScript. In short:

ECMAScript is a standard (just like QWERTY is a standard for keyboards). ECMAScript provides the rules, details, and guidelines that a scripting language must observe to be considered ECMAScript compliant. JavaScript is a general-purpose scripting language that conforms to the ECMAScript specification. There are various engines that can read JavaScript code, which is supplied by the webbrowser.

So the main features are from ECMA international, but web browser vendors are free to add features in their engines.